# Out of Range error copying data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel, copy

Hello all I am very very new to VBA just not old to Excel, and I'm attempting to write a macro that will allow a user to select a file, and then copy 2 separate ranges of data from that file and paste it into the original Active workbook.

Ok so after reviewing this I've changed my code to this:

```
Sub GetFastScanData()

'Add file name to Active Sheet
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String 

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If intChoice <> 0 Then
  strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
  Cells(1, 1) = strPath

  'Open Source WorkBook
  Dim sourceWB As Workbook
  Set sourceWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

  'Give names to items
  Dim Var1 As String
  Var1 = "BT16"

  Dim Var2 As Integer
  Var2 = 1

  Dim Var3 As String
  Var3 = "BU16"

  'Copy from Source to Target
  sourceWB.Sheets(Var2).Range("F1:F55000").Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks.Sheets("PI-2 data").Range(Var1)

  sourceWB.Sheets(Var2).Range("I2:I55000").Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks.Sheets("PI-2 data").Range(Var3)

  'Close Source WorkBook wo/Save
  sourceWB.Close False

End If

End Sub
```

My only problem now is that I think I'm getting an error due to the 12/9/2014 windows update? Compile Error: Data not Found

---

*original post:*

I'm really new with VBA, but i'm definitely not a rookie to Excel. I have an issue with a macro that is attempting to copy data from a selected file to the current workbook. I'm getting the out of range error for the italicized portion of the macro. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub GetFastScanData()

    'Add file name to Active Sheet
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    Cells(1, 65) = strPath

    'Open Source WorkBook
    Application.Workbooks.Open (strPath)

    'Give names to workbooks and items
    Dim Var1 As String, Var1R As String
    Var1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Var1R = "BT16"

    Dim Var2 As String, Var2R As String
    Var2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Var2R = 1

    Dim Var3 As String, Var3R As String
    Var3 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Var3R = "BU16"

    'Copy from Source to Target
    *sourceWB.Sheets(Var2R).Columns(6).EntireColumn.Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks(Var1).Sheets("PI-2 data").Range(VarR1)*

    Sheets(Var2R).Columns(9).EntireColumn.Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks(Var3).Sheets("PI-2 data").Range(Var3R)

    'Close Source WorkBook wo/Save
    Workbooks(Var2).Close False

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can see the italicized item. I did notice, however, that you're assigning `Var2R`, a `String`, to 1, an `Integer`. Are you certain that your assignments are correct?

Comment: Oh wow I totally forgot to italicize the part I'm asking about, thanks! and I may not be assigning the correct item to Var2R, i'm super new!

Comment: Your `Sub` needs to have a name and the `End Sub` needs to be on its own separate line at the end

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo. Sub has a name and End sub is in the proper location in VBA, I've reflected the change in an edit above.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting of the code as some of it had got messed up and commented out. I've also restored the text of the original post at the bottom - edits should clarify or improve the post but not remove large parts of the original post

Comment: Thanks barrowc for helping me out; it's my first post on this site period so I'll be sure to remember these things for future posts as well as brush up on the guidelines. I got a bit hasty and passionate trying to build this macro and just threw myself at this site!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems your original problem was solved. You should post that as an answer below, and ask a new question for your new problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to copy the entire column then the destination range needs to be in row 1. Otherwise there aren't enough rows to accommodate the values you are trying to paste in (remember this will copy the entry from every single row - all 1,048,576 of them - and not just the ones that you have actually used). If you only want part of the column copied then don't use `.EntireColumn`

It's unclear what `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3` are for as they all end up with the name of the same workbook. While each one is assigned the value of `ActiveWorkbook.Name`, nothing changes the active workbook between each assignment and thus they all get the same value

*edit:* replace `.Columns(6).EntireColumn.Copy` with `.Range("F2:F55000").Copy` and replace `.Columns(9).EntireColumn.Copy` with `.Range("I2:I55000").Copy`. There are other better ways to achieve this but this is the most easily understood.

You still need to work out exactly which workbook you think you are copying things to. `sourceWB` isn't defined anywhere and the other three variables all relate to the same workbook.

Should this:

```
'Open Source WorkBook
Application.Workbooks.Open (strPath)
```

instead be this:

```
'Open Source WorkBook
Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Set sourceWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
```

It's hard to interpret what `Var1` and `Var3` are meant to be for. The only obvious usage would be for the workbook which this macro is stored in but you may have other workbooks open that aren't explicitly referred to in the existing code. If they are intended to relate to the workbook with the macro stored in it then:

```
'Give names to items
Dim Var1R As String
Var1R = "BT16"

Dim Var2R As Integer
Var2R = 1

Dim Var3R As String
Var3R = "BU16"

'Copy from Source to Target
sourceWB.Sheets(Var2R).Range("F2:F55000").Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PI-2 data").Range(VarR1)

sourceWB.Sheets(Var2R).Range("I2:I55000").Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PI-2 data").Range(Var3R)

'Close Source WorkBook wo/Save
sourceWB.Close False
```

Comment: Ah I see, so I should use Range instead of .Entire Column? or something similar? and I pulled a lot of this code from bits and pieces on the internet. I'm extremely new and this is literally day 2 of me doing this so I'm very grateful for your help!

Comment: How much of the column do you actually want to copy?

Comment: Well, I would ideally want to copy a specific range of data from the column. this range would start from say.. the second row in a column and it could be between 43000 to 50000 cells long down the column depending on the file.

Comment: Can you determine the last row by looking at one of the columns? So, if I looked at the cells in column A, for example, would the last used cell be in the last row you wanted to copy?

Comment: The last row actually varies because the data has a different number of values each time. I guess I could just use what I'd expect the maximum number of values to be. For this purpose let's just say it's row 55000.

Comment: `LastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` then write `.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Copy`